# A-B Barcode Scan System -- Code39 Symbology Options

Tags: c#, compact-framework, barcode-scanner, inventory-management, code39

A customer is requiring that our company use an A-B Scan System to confirm 2 different container/master labels contain the same Part# barcodes on every container and every shipment. The issue is that both barcodes contain identical information -- so how can we prevent the operator from scanning the same label twice?

We've written an application (.Net 3.5CF) for the old WinCE6 scanners that are used in this dept, and we thought if the barcode formats were different then we could pull that information on each scan via the Intermec/Honeywell SDKs and use it to make sure that both format types are scanned for each container (also note: for boring reasons that I won't detail here, we are unable to change either of the labels to assist with this solution). Unfortunately, both labels are using the same format (Code39).

After reading through the Honeywell SDKs a bit more, it looks like we might have some other possibilities via symbology options -- but I'm having some trouble digging up more info about these (i.e. CodeMark, Symbology ID, etc)..

Is there anyone out there who has experience with an issue like this and could tell me if I'm on the right path..?  Is it possible that the identical barcodes (created by 2 different companies in 2 different facilities) might contain an obscure symbology option that is not identical..? Or maybe there is a "standard" solution that I've been unable to identify for this entire scenario?

Thanks!!

Comment: Code39 is a fairly simple format; the only real encoding option is whether or not to use a checksum character, but you would presumably be aware of any difference there as the codes wouldn't scan identically.  The only solution that comes to my mind would be to use a camera rather than a dedicated barcode scanner, and save the full images in addition to the decoded values - hopefully there would be *some* visible difference in the surrounding area, that would at least document the fact that you'd scanned two distinct labels.

Comment: Possibly you can add two hires images to show the different labels. Scanning one label can trigger an image to be taken of a defined area (called signature capture).